# Multiple problems: rotating, rigging

Tags: rigging, transforms

1:
I want to rotate mesh in object mode. If "manipulate center point" is inactive, it wont do anything.
If it is active, i can rotate only around X axis. (Same in edit mode)
Nothing is locked in Transform panel!

2:
In pose mode: If "manipulate center point" is inactive, I can not either translate or rotate.
If it is active, and i try to translate, it is rotating, but only the middle bones and the bones on the right side.

If I try to rotate, nothing happens.

I tried 2 versions of blender, but same problems.

Comment: 1: are you in right view? If so, then change the view with middle mouse button or use <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> to rotate around Y or Z axis 2: how are your bones connected?

Comment: 1: Now i know what was the problem about rotating in object mode. (my stupid mistake).     2: i am not sure how you mean the connection of the bones. But i still can not move them. In the Transform panel, the Location values are " inactive" , i can not change them, and they are not locked.     And 1 more problem: fex: if i rotate the right arm, the left one also rotate( only the mesh, the bone dont)

Comment: The unavailable translation is most likely because it's a connected child bone. You are only able to rotate or scale a connected child. You can keep the parent/child hierarchy while allowing translation of that bone by going into edit mode, select the child bone in question, press alt-P and disconnect bone. If you drag the bone away, you'll see a dotted line connecting the two. This means they are still in a hierarchy.

Comment: THX, the Alt+P was the solution for my problem.

Comment: Questions should be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

The "manipulate center point" setting is only useful when you have more than 1 object selected.

If you have (eg) 2 cubes selected then without "manipulate center point" (lighter icon background), the two cubes rotate together as a group, as a whole single object.

Enabling "manipulate center point" (darker icon background), the two cubes rotate individually *around* their group (ideal) center.

So, if you wish to rotate only 1 object, deselect that setting and try again.